# CipherCloud and Live Agent Compatiable

Tags: liveagent

Our organization is currently using Cipher Cloud for encryption.  We're looking at implementing Live Agent for our call center.  I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with using these two products together?  If there are any issues that you ran into and what are they?  Any additional pros and cons on using these products together would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CipherCloud supports encryption of chat content generated by Live Agent, using our standard and proven integration methodology.